# WSO2 Data Service merge two columns?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I've created a query that returns a set of results and I would like to merge two of the columns is this possible and whats the best way to do it. So for example I have two columns Value and Units.

```
Value | Units
1       Year(s)
```

What I want to do is merge these columns into one so it would become

```
Length |
1 Year(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by merging the columns within my SQL statement. Example of the SQL statement is like this:

```
Select col1, col2 || ' ' || col3, from table
```

The above statement merges col2 and col3 and adds a space between them.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a ESB along with the DSS. So that the data service is exposed via the ESB. The ESB will do the necessary data merging before sending the response to the service consumer. For this you can use either the enrich[1] or payload factory[2] mediator.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Enrich+Mediator

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/PayloadFactory+Mediator